# couldnot update datagrid to dbf using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dbf

I am new in programming but learning and research at many time without any course, so i am faced problem at many time. Stack Over flow is right place of solving my issue for me.

This time i have update datagridview to .dbf file for another application where using .dbf database. So Please give me a better solution to prepare my application.

My error is **"Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information."**

<
My Code is given below.

```
Dim con As New OleDbConnection
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
Dim con1 As New OleDbConnection
Dim ds1 As New DataSet
Dim dt1 As New DataTable
Dim da1 As New OleDbDataAdapter
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       con.ConnectionString = "Provider=vfpoledb.1;Data Source=C:\dbf_folder;Collating Sequence=machine;"
    con.Open()
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from voterlist.dbf", con)
    da.Fill(dt)
    dbfdatagrid.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
    con.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub btnupdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnupdate.Click
    con1.Close()
    con1.ConnectionString = "Provider=vfpoledb.1;Data Source=C:\dbf_folder1;Collating Sequence=machine;"
    con1.Open()
    da1 = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from voterlist.dbf", con1)
    Dim cb = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da1)
    Dim primaryKey(1) As DataColumn
    primaryKey(1) = dt1.Columns("areaid")
    dt1.PrimaryKey = primaryKey
    da1.Fill(dt)
    dt.Merge(dt1)
    da1.Update(dt)
End Sub
```

Comment: Does your database table have a primary key? If not then the command builder is unable to uniquely identify a record in order to update or delete. Also, set the `MissingSchemaAction` of the data adapter to `AddWithKey` before calling `Fill`.

Comment: By the way, think about what the `New` keyword actually does. It is NOT part of a declaration. It actually creates a new object. Why are you creating two data adapters when you create the form, then another one when you retrieve the data and then yet another when you save?  You only need one data adapter so get rid of one of the variables and only use the `New` keyword once.  You also don't need two different connection objects. If you're going to create the objects as you use them then don't use member variables.

Comment: Why are you using two different `DataSets` as well?  All you need is one `DataTable`.  Get rid of all the `DataSets` and one of the `DataTables`. Create one `DataTable` and pass it to a `Fill` call at startup and then pass the same `DataTable` to an `Update` call at save.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the DataSet/DataTable what the primary key is:

```
' For dataset DS, assumed there is one table
Dim PrimaryKey(1) As DataColumn
PrimaryKey(1) = ds.Tables(0).Columns("ID")
DS.Tables(0).PrimaryKey = PrimaryKey

' For DataTable DT
Dim PrimaryKey(1) As DataColumn
PrimaryKey(1) = dt.Columns("ID")
dt.PrimaryKey = PrimaryKey
```

**Update**

You are using the correct driver, you need to create a Unique column in the DBF.  To do this execute this SQL on the DBF prior to using it:

```
ALTER TABLE voterlist ALTER COLUMN areaid INT UNIQUE (I assume an integer column, if character, areaid C(somenumber) where somenumber is the size of the column)
```

This will create an index on the column areaid which will (should) be used as the primary key.

Comment: your code is working within dataset but while i will update "da.update(dt)" thats after showing the error. thank you

Comment: Ok ... it's been a while since I've had to deal with DBF's, you need to define the primary key on the DBF.  Do you know how the DBF was created (Dbase, FoxPro, etc)?  I see you are using OLEDB.  Do you have access to the product that created the DBF?  If you do you may be able to define the key without destroying the data.  Failing that you'll have to create a DBF that has the ID column defined as the primary key, copy the data to the new DBFand then proceed from there, assuming that's an option.

Comment: thanks a lot for reply me, this DBF created by FoxPro and please share to me anycode been update to dbf , thats after i will try